# Find out the mean time between privileges

Tags: support, privileges, data-explorer

With reputation people gain [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). The privileges are not evenly distanced, and neither grows somebody's reputation linearly.

I wonder whether it's possible to calculate the mean time between privileges for a user, e.g. with [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

I'm not very familiar with it, but perhaps one of you has some fun building a query.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with the data explorer, but it would be very interesting to see the results.

Comment: The data explorer doesn't include deleted posts, but you do get to keep reputation from deleted posts if they're beyond a certain age. I don't know how much impact that has, but you could probably still come up with a rough estimate from DE.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, the votes are still in there for deleted posts. It would be some gnarly query, but I think you could do this with SEDE.

Comment: If it's not 100% accurate regarding deleted posts, that's fine for me.

Comment: I wonder what use this particular metric would have, though. If you are a very knowledgable engineer and can answer a lot of questions (especially questions with bounties on them), then you can gain privileges in a very short period of time. So this metric is really just going to be a measure of some unknown combination of user experience, activity and luck.

Comment: @JDB: looking at your 10k and my 7k profile, it's a quite steady curve, looking more like effort than luck. But of course, if you hit a "hot question" streak, this may happen.

Comment: I think it would be useful to identify gaps in advancement. For me personally, once I hit 5k rep I basically stopped using SO for a while since the next milestone (10k mod tools) was so far away. Finding similar hotspots I think would be a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus - Not to mention the occasional flat spot generated by a 'rage quit' timeout.